# Unable to locate elements present under flex in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

I was trying to automate a  [Demo Website link](https://demo.competethemes.com/). But was not able to locate the **Shop Now** button using my relative path **//a[contains(text(),'Shop Now')]**. I noticed flex was written in the DOM does that affect it?

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

[Shop Now Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUqu3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Shop Now</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *LINK_TEXT*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://demo.competethemes.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#iframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Shop Now"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://demo.competethemes.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Shop Now']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: can u please tell why my path is not working here

Comment: I'm seeing this flex word in google ads page also just wanna how to handle these types of pages or any blog containing the explanation

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yea it worked thnx.. But again one small doubt ... after clicking on that button on the next page I'm trying to click on "View Demo" which is also present under the iframe with the same path = "//*[@id=\"iframe\"]".  so when trying to switch frames I'm getting "no such element"

Comment: Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to locate and click

```
button= driver.execute_script('retun document.querySelector("#header-promo > div > div > div.content > div.button > a")')
button.click();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with java scripts as of now. can u please tell through the XPath approach

Comment: Check the detailed answer of  undetected Selenium for xpath